# Gradle: multiple application.properties for multi-project build with profile support

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, properties, application.properties

Basically, I want to have something like the following structure:

```
├── ...
├── core-module
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       |   └── java
│       |   └── resources
│       |       └── application.properties
│       |       ├── application-dev.properties
│       |       ├── application-test.properties 
│       |       └── application-prod.properties
│       └── test
│           └── java
├── dogs-module
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       |   └── java
│       |   └── resources
│       |       └── application.properties
│       |       ├── application-dev.properties
│       |       ├── application-test.properties 
│       |       └── application-prod.properties
│       └── test
│           └── java
├── cats-module
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       |   └── java
│       |   └── resources
│       |       └── application.properties
│       |       ├── application-dev.properties
│       |       ├── application-test.properties 
│       |       └── application-prod.properties
│       └── test
│           └── java
├── birds-module
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       |   └── java
│       |   └── resources
│       |       └── application.properties
│       |       ├── application-dev.properties
│       |       ├── application-test.properties 
│       |       └── application-prod.properties
│       └── test
│           └── java
├── src?
└── ...
```

- `dogs`, `cats` and `birds` modules have the `core` (*or* base/common) module as a dependency. For Gradle, it's `compile project(':core')`.
- `dogs`, `cats` and `birds` modules are not related in any way. The only common feature is the `core` project.

I am planning the default root `src` directory to be empty but I could use `application.properties`, `application-{profile}.properties` here for some initialization too, if possible.

```
├── ...
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        └── resources
            └── application.properties
            ├── application-dev.properties
            ├── application-test.properties 
            └── application-prod.properties
```

How can I load properties this way for an environment profile so that properties in the next file could override properties from the previous one?

For instance, `core` ←  `dogs`:

- root-application.properties
- root-application-prod.properties
- core-application.properties
- core-application-prod.properties
- dogs-application.properties
- dogs-application-prod.properties

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @blubb, not really. The time I had for this task expired, and I made a workaround solution by copying some files and some content here and there. So, this question is kind of still open.